# Give input to a cmd process running using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

I have a process running using ProcessBuilder in java that runs some commands in command line. I get the following output :

```
    Fetching data ...
    Data successfully fetched.
    An older version of Data already present on the System
    1.Install the newer version
    2.Keep the previous version
    Please Type 1 to get the newer version or 2 to keep the older version
```

Now the fetching takes around 1 second. So, I am not able to figure out how to enter either of the options in command line in the single running process.

Comment: What command are you running? How are you running it ([mcve]) ? Typically, you find the command line flag you need to tell the command up-front what decision you want to take. If that's not possible, you can look into the unix "expect" command.

Comment: Are you asking how to accept keyboard after displaying the line `Please Type 1...` ?